# Why can't I use brackets in this while-loop?

Tags: java

For clarity I want to use brackets in the following while-loop. But, I get compilation errors with brackets.

I can run this code

```
while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null)  in.nextLine();
    in.nextLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) 
    {
        data[0][j] =  Integer.parseInt(in.findInLine("[0-9]+|-"));
        in.nextLine();
    }
```

But I get errors with brackets

```
while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null) 
{ 
    in.nextLine();
    in.nextLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) 
    {
        data[0][j] =  Integer.parseInt(in.findInLine("[0-9]+|-"));
        in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Error: `NumberFormatException:null`.

So, how should i interpret

```
while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null)  in.nextLine();
    in.nextLine();
```

Comment: the two code blocks are not equivalent, due to language syntax (because of the brackets)

Comment: I'm guessing the second example is what you wanted the program to do. Please add to the question what you're reading in and what you're trying to do with the program ([Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) if you would like help with the numberformatexception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding brackets for clarity is a great idea indeed. This question is a prime example as to why: Your indentation leads to confusion here :)

```
while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null)  in.nextLine();
```

Equals (and should be converted to):

```
while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null) {
  in.nextLine();
}
```

So, for the question:

> So, how should i interpret
>
> ```
> while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null)  in.nextLine();
>     in.nextLine();
> ```

The answer is:

```
while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null) {
  in.nextLine();
}
in.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Without brackets, the loop only apply to the first statement. So your code should be

```
while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null) 
{
    in.nextLine();
}
in.nextLine();
for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) 
{
    data[0][j] =  Integer.parseInt(in.findInLine("[0-9]+|-"));
    in.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code block is equivalent to

```
while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null) {
  in.nextLine();
}

in.nextLine();

for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) 
{
  data[0][j] =  Integer.parseInt(in.findInLine("[0-9]+|-"));
  in.nextLine();
}
```

Without more context what you want to do we not correct your code.